# How to prevent D-Bus from starting a (disabled) other daemon?

Tags: debian, systemd, d-bus

Recently I noticed that the `rtkit-daemon` process running on my Debian 10.4 machine may be interferring with a custom server application on that machine. So I wanted to disable that realtime kit daemon like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop rtkit-daemon.service
$ sudo systemctl disable rtkit-daemon.service
```

That correctly stopped (and disabled) the `rtkit-daemon` process. However, after a while I noticed that it is running again, and in syslog I found the following lines:

```
Jun 12 16:15:12 box-63 dbus-daemon[453]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.6746' (uid=1000 pid=11857 comm="python pipecheck.py")
Jun 12 16:15:12 box-63 systemd[1]: Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jun 12 16:15:12 box-63 dbus-daemon[453]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1'
Jun 12 16:15:12 box-63 systemd[1]: Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
```

That `python pipecheck.py` is our custom application.
Why does D-Bus want to start the realtime kit for our application in the first place?

Anyway, so apparently the `dbus-daemon` has restarted the `rtkit-daemon`.
How can i prevent that and disable the realtime kit daemon for good?

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to Desktop Bus bus activation!  It is a pain, and should be avoided.

A Desktop Bus client (of some kind) is asking the Desktop Bus broker for communication with the `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1` D-Bus server.
When the `rtkit-daemon` program is running, it registers itself with the D-Bus broker as this name.
When it is not running, the broker invokes *D-Bus bus activation*.

When a client asks the D-Bus broker this in such circumstances, the broker looks at what is specfied in a `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.service` file.
(This is *not* a systemd service unit file, but a D-Bus configuration file living somewhere under `/usr/{local/,}share/dbus-1/system-services/`, D-Bus also using the `.service` extension.)
The broker learns from this file that on only systemd systems the `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1` server is managed as a `rtkit-daemon.service` systemd service.

The broker speaks to `systemd` over the same Desktop Bus, using an idiosyncratic and undocumented `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Activator` *D-Bus* service name, asking it to activate the `rtkit-daemon.service` *systemd* service with an `ActivationRequest` message.
This undocumented activation function [has no notion](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/0894f08bf14b09ef0436ed11268d43dbcdd88ee7/src/core/dbus.c#L180) of only activating the service if enabled.
It *always* activates the service, even if it is disabled.

So, ironically, you cannot disable `rtkit-daemon` using the obvious method of disabling it, the `disable` command.
You can instead:

- … override the `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.service` file with one of your own that contains no ways to activate the `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1` D-Bus server;
- … find out what D-Bus client is asking for `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1`, with `busctl monitor`, and stop it; or
- … *mask* the `rtkit-daemon.service` systemd service, so that *systemd itself* does not know how to activate it even if the Desktop Bus broker requests its activation via the idiosyncratic and undocumented API.

This is one reason that my `system-control` has a `reset` verb (which starts/stops a service according to its current enable/disable state) and my replacement `dbus-daemon-launch-helper` invokes `system-control reset` rather than `system-control activate`.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Avoid Desktop Bus (D-Bus) bus activation](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/avoid-dbus-bus-activation.html)*
  .  nosh.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. "`reset`". [`system-control`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/system-control.xml#JOB).  *nosh Guide*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. [`dbus-daemon-launch-helper`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/dbus-daemon-launch-helper.xml).  *nosh Guide*.

Comment: Found out the hard way that you can't mask rtkit-daemon.service *for a user*, only for the entire system. `systemctl --user` doesn't even see rtkit-daemon.service! How do you go about overriding the DBus activation (your first proposed solution)? Can this be overriden for a single user?

Comment: Ah, you're supposed to be able to override in `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.service`. However, I've tried to drop a file in there that "starts" /bin/true, and still the real rtkit-daemon gets activated. I'll ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

poke it the hard way:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/dbus-daemon /usr/bin/dbus-daemonx
sudo ln -s /bin/true /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
```

you could also remove the original file and get it back by reinstalling the package...

the same aproach is working for other unwanted stuff^^