# mask dbus-activated service (rtkit) via ~/.local/share?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, d-bus

I've been trying to mask a dbus-activated service (rtkit-daemon) via the "standard service dirs" location `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/`. The corresponding system file, which I want to override, is at `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/`.

This idea was suggested by [How to prevent D-Bus from starting a (disabled) other daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592542/how-to-prevent-d-bus-from-starting-a-disabled-other-daemon)

Specifically, I've dropped a file `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.service` into `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services`:

```
Name=org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1
#Exec=/usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
Exec=/bin/true
#SystemdService=rtkit-daemon.service
User=root
```

... but still the "real" `rtkit-daemon.service` keeps getting activated (by pulseaudio, firefox).

I am aware that I can mask the global systemd `rtkit-daemon.service`, but I want to only mask it for a specific user (and via dbus, not systemd). Why isn't my drop-in overriding the global setting? Is there some way to debug `dbus`'s search path, or see if doesn't parse my file? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

But `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/` is for "standard **session** service directories", and the D-Bus service that you want to override is **system-wide** (its service file is in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/`

Besides, the D-Bus service file `org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1.service` uses

```
SystemdService=rtkit-daemon.service
```

so it's started by systemd, not D-Bus

Comment: Yes, as in IDK what is a system service vs a session service (who prints the search paths). But no, it's impossible that Firefox itself calls systemd (I've tried with ESR appimages). See http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/avoid-dbus-bus-activation.html

Comment: Also, these entries in the systemd journal: `dbus-daemon[601]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' ...`

Comment: See  

[dbus-daemon] (https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html)  

Section "DESCRIPTION", for the explanation of "system service vs a session service"  

For the directories where D-Bus service files are searched for each type see

Section "CONFIGURATION FILE"  

Elements:  

<standard_session_servicedirs/>  

<standard_system_servicedirs/>  

Note that in this section the sentence  

"On Unix, the standard session service directories are:"  

Should read  

"On Unix, the standard system-wide service directories are"